# How can we sort news by Top-News in 2sxc?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

on the page for the news app it say:
The app has features like Top-News extract (for the home page or similar)
So I was wondering if there is anything like a number-of-views counter or something we can use in the news app. We would really be interested in something like this anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really recommend do this, but you could add code to the news items Detail View's code that increments a Counter. For a large site with a thousands of view, this is a very bad idea to do it in 2sxc using Content Types.

But, if you have a Content Type name NewsTicks with two fields, `ArticleEntityId` and `Counter`, both numbers, when the article is created, you would then:

```
    var fields = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    fields.Add("ArticleEntityId", newsItem.EntityId);
    fields.Add("Counter", 0);
    App.Data.Create(contentTypeName: "NewsTicks", values: fields);
```

Then each time the page is viewed you could use code like this to increment the counter. I am linking to the Issue/Feature Request I added because it details a bit more info about why this is not a great idea on a busy site.

**2sic/2sxc, Issues:**

[Ability to Update an Entity's Fields without Creating History items](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2425)

Then all you'd need is some LINQ to get the sorted list of Top News articles.

Answer (score 0):

So there's nothing built in, but since it's all open-source, you could easily add it.

Note that 2sxc data model is optimized for infrequent writing and mass-reading scenarios, so updating data on each view wouldn't be the best way to do this. But you could just put it in a SQL table or something or use another counting/tracking system for that.

Comment: Right, so that's exactly the issue I think, how to do this...
Are there any examples ?? I've looked in the apps catalog but no app seems to have something that will update the data for an item on the front end.

Comment: You won't find such an example on 2sxc apps as they don't usually have this. So you'll basically need to find a solution not related to 2sxc and just adapt/use that.

Comment: You could also use a simple existing web service like https://countapi.xyz/